# Doesn @Pattern of javax.validation.constraints works with non-ASCII Unicode correct?

Tags: java, regex, validation, unicode

I need to validate entered domain name. And I use javax.validation with hibernate-validator:6.0.9.Final for this.

My regex is `((([\p{L}0-9])+(-?[\p{L}0-9])*)\.)*[\p{L}0-9](-?[\p{L}0-9])+\.\p{L}{2,}` Also I tried `\p{Alpha}` with flag `(?U)` instead of `\p{L}`. It works in IntelliJ IDEA for example. So I put it to @Pattern annotation. Test run from IDEA works fine. But test run from Gradle doesn't work - validator doesn't recognize domain name with non-ACII characters, for example, cyrillic domain "мой-домен.рф" causes ConstraintViolationException.

In javadoc for java.util.regex.Pattern class they say that embedded flag expression (?U) works only for US-ASCII symbols only:

> When this flag is specified then the (US-ASCII only) Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes are in conformance with Unicode Technical Standard #18: Unicode Regular Expression Annex C: Compatibility Properties.

So I can agree that `\p{Alpha}` may not work with non-ASCII letters. But why `\p{L}` doesn't work?

Who is wrong: hibernate-validator that really works with this only for US-ASCII or IDEA that works fine with all Unicode letters? And why test run from IDEA works and test run from Gradle doesn't with the same JVM? Some different command line arguments were set? I set UTF-8 as file encoding in both of IDEA and Gradle script.

Comment: Are you sure you refer to appropriate documentation? In Java regex, `\p{L}` does not require `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag to match Unicode letters, it does by default.

Comment: I use (?U) only with \p{Alpha}.

Answer (score 1):

My bad was in wrong setting UTF-8 encoding in Gradle script.

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

in build.gradle and

```
systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8
```

in gradle.properties actually don't work. Only

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

in build.gradle works. With this setting tests are correct in both environments.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simplified pattern which demonstrates that the Unicode support works.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)[-.\\p{L}]+");
    String s = "321";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + pattern.matcher(s).matches());
    s = "mia-domajno.rf";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + pattern.matcher(s).matches());
    s = "мой-домен.рф";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + pattern.matcher(s).matches());
```

Will yield (as expected):

```
321 -> false
mia-domajno.rf -> true
мой-домен.рф -> true
```

So the culprit is the composition of the regex. For which I do not have a clear head at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. I already found real culprit - it's me :) I wrong set encoding for compiler in Gradle